# Did someone use onPrimaryClipChanged?

Tags: android, clip

There is a problem, when i use OnPrimaryClipChangedListener to lesten clipboard change.
it always get twice. can somebody help me?

Code is like this:

```
private OnPrimaryClipChangedListener clipListener = new OnPrimaryClipChangedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onPrimaryClipChanged() {
        Log.d("mytag", '--------->clip--------->');
    }
}
```

when I clip, I get two logs output. Does someone has the same problem?

> D/mytag --------->clip--------->
>   D/mytag --------->clip--------->

Comment: It does not get called twice, but it gets called once per registered PrimaryClipChangedListener. Usually the double (or multiple) calls happen, when you accidentally register your Listener more than once. Can you post some code of where and how you register your Listener?

Comment: Please check this...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18391701/clipboardmanager-onprimaryclipchangedlistener-is-called-twice-for-every-copy?answertab=oldest#tab-top

Comment: printing 3 times in my case.

Comment: I solve this problem, see my answer : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18391701/clipboardmanager-onprimaryclipchangedlistener-is-called-twice-for-every-copy/28230843#28230843