# ClipboardManager OnPrimaryClipChangedListener is called twice for every copy

Tags: android, clipboardmanager

When I copy text to the clipboard onPrimaryClipChanged method is called twice. Any ideas why?

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    final ClipboardManager cliboardManager = (ClipboardManager) getSystemService(CLIPBOARD_SERVICE);

    cliboardManager
            .addPrimaryClipChangedListener(new OnPrimaryClipChangedListener() {

                @Override
                public void onPrimaryClipChanged() {
                    ClipData clipData = cliboardManager.getPrimaryClip();
                    System.out
                            .println("********** clip changed, clipData: "
                                    + clipData.getItemAt(0));
                }
            });
    return true;
}
```

Test case:
Copying the text "continue" from the BBC web site will result in the following output:

> continue
>
> continue

But if I debug the program I can see that the clipData object has value:

> ClipData { text/plain {T:continue } }

the first time onPrimaryClipChanged() is called and

> ClipData { text/plain "BBC - Homepage" {T:continue } }

the next time onPrimaryClipChanged() is called.

So basically the first time ClipDescription is { text/plain } and the second time is ClipDescription { text/plain "BBC - Homepage" } (i.e including the title of the web page)

Comment: Are you sure you havent accidentally registered two listeners? :)

Comment: Double setting of the clipboard might be a bug in some apps. I get two clipboard messages from Chrome, and they appear to be identical (both text/html, all fields seem to be the same, and `toString` returns the same html both times). I tested on Whatsapp, Youtube, Hangouts, and the default messaging app and all of them set the clipboard just once. There may be a reason why Chrome is doing this, but I don't have time to dig in their source right now.

Answer (score 10):

I assume you didn't register multiple listeners, I can't say it is bug, you still you can workaround it. Try something like this:

```
   String mPreviousText = "";

   cliboardManager
                .addPrimaryClipChangedListener(new OnPrimaryClipChangedListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onPrimaryClipChanged() {
                        ClipData clipData = cliboardManager.getPrimaryClip();
                        System.out
                                .println("********** clip changed, clipData: "
                                        + clipData.getItemAt(0));
                         ClipData.Item item = clipData.getItemAt(0);
                         if(mPreviousText.equals(item.getText().toString())) return;
                         else{
                            /// do something
                            mPrevousText = item.getText().toString();
                         }
                    }
                });
```

Comment: It's a nice workaround, but when the user does want to copy the same text twice, it won't work :(.

Comment: @DaveChen If you copy the same text twice, it will be still the same text on the clipboard.

Comment: +1 because I actually did end up using this workaround, but the problem would be that `/// do something` won't be hit twice if the user does decide to copy the text twice.

Answer (score 6):

I meet this problem too, finally I know why it will call multi times!!!
Usually we `addPrimaryClipChangedListener()`, but we don't `removePrimaryClipChangedListener()`.

See:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#CLIPBOARD_SERVICE

> Use with getSystemService(String) to retrieve a ClipboardManager for accessing and modifying the contents of the global clipboard.

It means we should `removePrimaryClipChangedListener()` manually!

My solution code :

```
ClipboardManager myClipBoard ;
static boolean bHasClipChangedListener = false;

ClipboardManager.OnPrimaryClipChangedListener mPrimaryClipChangedListener = new ClipboardManager.OnPrimaryClipChangedListener() {
    public void onPrimaryClipChanged() {
        ClipData clipData = myClipBoard.getPrimaryClip();
        Log.d("henrytest", "********** clip changed, clipData: " + clipData.getItemAt(0));
    }
};

private void RegPrimaryClipChanged(){
    if(!bHasClipChangedListener){
        myClipBoard.addPrimaryClipChangedListener(mPrimaryClipChangedListener);
        bHasClipChangedListener = true;
    }
}
private void UnRegPrimaryClipChanged(){
    if(bHasClipChangedListener){
        myClipBoard.removePrimaryClipChangedListener(mPrimaryClipChangedListener);
        bHasClipChangedListener = false;
    }
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    myClipBoard = (ClipboardManager) Clipboard.this.getSystemService(android.content.Context.CLIPBOARD_SERVICE);
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    RegPrimaryClipChanged();
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    UnRegPrimaryClipChanged();
}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    //UnRegPrimaryClipChanged();
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    //UnRegPrimaryClipChanged();
}
```

Comment: If you place UnRegPrimaryClipChanged() to onPause() all other placements to onStop() and onDestroy() are needless.

Answer (score 2):

This is my workaround to prevent ClipboardManager OnPrimaryClipChangedListener is called twice for every copy.

```
long lastCopiedTime = 0;
ClipboardManager.OnPrimaryClipChangedListener onPrimaryClipChangedListener = new ClipboardManager.OnPrimaryClipChangedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onPrimaryClipChanged() {
                ClipboardManager clipBoard = (ClipboardManager) getSystemService(CLIPBOARD_SERVICE);
                String pasteData = "";
                ClipData.Item item = clipBoard.getPrimaryClip().getItemAt(0);
                if (System.currentTimeMillis() - lastCopiedTime > TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMillis(1)) {
                    if (StringUtils.isNotBlank(item.getText())) {
                        String s = item.getText().toString();
                        if (StringUtils.isNotBlank(s)) {
                            pasteData = s.trim();
                            if (StringUtils.isNotBlank(pasteData)) {
                                  /// do something here
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                lastCopiedTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            }
        }
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

// Prevention duplicate action of OnPrimaryClipChangedListener.

```
private ExecutorService mThreadPool = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
static boolean isExpireData = true;

class hasExpireData implements Runnable {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        isExpireData = true;
    }

}

private ClipboardManager.OnPrimaryClipChangedListener mOnPrimaryClipChangedListener =
        new ClipboardManager.OnPrimaryClipChangedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onPrimaryClipChanged() {
        Log.d(TAG, "onPrimaryClipChanged");
        ClipData clip = mClipboardManager.getPrimaryClip();

        Thread expireData = new Thread(new hasExpireData());
        new Handler().postDelayed(expireData, 500); // 0.5 seconds wait...

        if(isExpireData) {
            isExpireData = false;
            mThreadPool.execute(new TextRunnable(
                    clip.getItemAt(0).getText()));
        }

    }
};

private class TextRunnable implements Runnable {
    public TextRunnable(CharSequence text) {
        // text store to this class
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        // text other process
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

found out why it get called twice , in the https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/android/content/ClipboardManager.OnPrimaryClipChangedListener , it says:

```
This is called when the result of ClipDescription#getClassificationStatus() changes, 
as well as when new clip data is set. 

So in cases where text classification is performed, 
this callback may be invoked multiple times for the same clip.
```

That should be the reason. And the solution has two from the previous devs

- 1). using `nowTime - lastTime > 100ms`
- 2). using `if(clipText == prevClipText)`

The second case won't cover `clipping a same text twice`, and we want to log every copy action (for analytics, for example), so the first solution might be better in this case

Answer (score 0):

The solutions in the comments all have flaws, and the correct approach is to:

Compare the getTimestamp() of the ClipDescription between this clipboard data and the previous clipboard data. If Timestamps are the same, it means they are the same clipboard data.

```
    ClipboardManager clipboardManager = (ClipboardManager) getSystemService(Context.CLIPBOARD_SERVICE);
    clipboardManager.addPrimaryClipChangedListener(new ClipboardManager.OnPrimaryClipChangedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPrimaryClipChanged() {
            ClipData data = clipboardManager.getPrimaryClip();
            long clipDataTimestamp = data.getDescription().getTimestamp();
            // compare the timestamp with the previous one
        }
    });
```